# Numerical calculation of a Fourier Transform

Tags: numerical-methods, polar-coordinates, fourier-transform, mathematical-modeling, computational-mathematics

I am trying to Fourier transform the following:

$\int \frac{d^2r}{(2\pi)^2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{r}} \; \delta (\rho-r) e^{i\alpha \phi_{r}} \; e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}$

where $\rho$ is a constant; $\vec{r}=\{\hat{x},\hat{y}\}$ and $\vec{k}=\{\hat{k_x},\hat{k_y}\}$. Analytically one would use polar coordinates and obtain something like

$\frac{\sqrt{\rho}}{2\pi} e^{i\alpha \phi_k} J_{\alpha}(k \rho)$

but numerically, I couldn't find out the way to calculate a Fourier transform over the finite integration range. So I went to cartesian coordinate system to take it at least in MMA:

```
\[Alpha] = 1.; k = 5.;

f[x_, y_] := Sqrt[(1)/(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])] KroneckerDelta[
Sqrt[8] - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] Exp[I \[Alpha] ArcTan[x, y]] ;

NN = 100000;

signal = Table[0.0, {i, 1, NN}];

For[i = 0, i < NN, i++, x = i/NN * \[Pi]; signal[[i + 1]] = f[x, 1.]]
Show[ListLinePlot[Re[InverseFourier[signal]]]]
```

This produces zero. I am not that great at Fourier transforming, but shouldn't the result be independent of the choice of the coordinate system? Shouldn't DFT be analogous to continuous FT when the number of steps is big enough?

What am I doing wrong? Does anybody know if this is even possible to calculate this transform numerically in any coordinate system?

Thanks a lot for any help, prospective, guidance!

P.S.: final goal is to calculate it using FFTW library. MMA is just a draft to check if such thing is even possible.

Comment: I haven't picked through your M'ma code in detail, but ... did you remember to include the Jacobian for your change of variable?  If not, you are treating various polar circles as if they all had the same circumference.  Since $\mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y = r \ \mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta$, you should have an extra $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$ somewhere.  (Which you might.  As I say, I haven't really dug in yet.)

Comment: @Eric Towers Analytically - yes; numerically, I was trying to do cartesian -> Jacobian=1

Comment: That's not how it works, from what I remember. For cartesian $J=1$, for polar $J=r$...

Comment: You don't seem to have transformed $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 r}{(2\pi)^2}$, which would require a Jacobian term that you don't have.  I can't guess what this should be since this is currently malformed -- is it a single integral or a double integral?  what is the differential element?  For the latter, I would have expected $\mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\theta$, but what you have written is not a 2-form, so apparently you intend an iterated integral with respect to $r$ twice?

Comment: @Eric Towers $d^2 r= d \vec{r}$ by convention. Pick the coordinate system yourself. Form what I understand, it should not change the result. When I was doing it analytically, I have used polar with $J=r$. Numerically, I used cartesian with $J=1$.